# SQL command to store data of one table as column name in another table

Tags: mysql

I have a table name Table1

```
     string    result
     abc    |    10
     xyz    |    20
     opq    |    23
```

and another table named Table2

```
id   xyz 
1  | 20
```

I want to check whether the rows under column name **string** are present as a column name in table 2.If present enter the **result** of table1 into the column name of table2
(ex: xyz 20)
If not present then make a column name in table2 with that name and store **result** under that column name.

Say, abc is not present as a column name in table 2 so I want to create a column name by that name and store 10 under it
But for xyz we see that xyz is already present as a column name in table2 so we store 20 under xyz.

How can I do it? I am not able to start.

Comment: Please tag your dbms, is it mysql or sql-server?

Comment: I am using MySQL database

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this approach? Because it sounds like a really bad idea.